# MBCalendar Kit integration in iOS

Tags: ios7, calendar, uikit, mbcalendarkit

I have got the source code of Calendar component from https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/README.md

I want to integrate this into my app. How do I do it?

Can I import any of its frameworks etc?

I tried copying all the files into my Xcode project, but it makes the app heavy!

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [CKDemoViewController new];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/README.md):

> MBCalendarKit requires Quartz, Core Graphics, UIKit, and Foundation. The Unit Tests build against the XCTest framework. Xcode should take care of all those except QuartzCore.framework. If you're building the tests, you may have to link to XCTest yourself, as well.
>
> Aside from the framework dependencies described above, you'll want everything in the CalendarKit folder.

Comment: Dear Moshe i have a problem with the when i am trying to present in in my viewcontroller in ios7 that time i m not able to presenting a calendarview

Comment: it stuck the view and i have to kill application.